# Passing a param for a apply-template select in xlst, .net

Tags: .net, xslt, xpath

I have the following in my xslt file:

```
<xsl:param name="predicate" select="//Event" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="$predicate" />
```

And this works fine, but now I'd like to change the param from my .net code.

```
var args = new XsltArgumentList();
args.AddParam("predicate", "", "//Event[@valid]");
xmlviewer.TransformArgumentList = args;
```

but no matter what i pass in for predicate, I get the error **"Expression must evaluate to a node set."**

Is there a way to pass the xpath selector into the transform?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete solution. :)

Comment: Do note that that parameter declaration must be a top level one in order to pass its value to the XSLT processor at invocation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> args.AddParam("predicate", "", "//Event[@valid]");
> ```

You are passing just a string to the stylesheet, but the stylesheet is using the `predicate` parameter as a node-set -- it performs an `<xsl:apply-templates>` on it.

**The solution**

Evaluate the XPath expression you are now passing as a string. For example, use the **[`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea193ac.aspx)** method of **[XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x81sf5a.aspx)**. Then pass as parameter to the transformation the resulting **[XPathNodeIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.aspx)**.

Comment: +1 Good answer. You can pass any data type allowed by XSLT/XPath Data Model

Comment: @Dimitre: So, I'm close, I've got a XPathNavigator and I used select() to get a XPathNodeIterator. But what did you mean by the "pass as a parameter to the transformation"? I'm not sure how to get the nodes selected by the Iterator to be transformed by my xslt. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wavel: You already have that code: the same `args.AddParam()`, but with the XPathNodeIterator for the third argument.

Comment: @Dimitre: so close and yet so far :) I figured I would pass in the xpathnodeiterator using AddParam(), but what do I do with it inside the xslt? Can you provide me a few line example of xsl?

Comment: @Wavel: You have it: `<xsl:apply-templates select="$predicate" />` or you can simply verify it by: `<xsl:copy-of select="$predicate" />`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, `$predicate` here is the *string* `"//Event[@valid]"` - you have essentially done:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="'//Event[@valid]'"/>
```

i.e. tried to evaluate a template on a string. That can't work. You *can*, however, test for *values* of `@valid`, for example

```
<xsl:param name="valid" select="" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Event[@valid=$valid]" />
```

Of course, since xslt is xml, another way to approach this would be to load the xslt into a DOM and *replace* the xpath expression prior to execution.